# RubyでTwitterのDMを取得する方法

Tags: ruby, twitter

RubyでツイッターのDMを取得しその結果から処理を実行したい考えです。
ひとまずDMを取得してみようと考え、調べた結果から以下のコードを実行してみましたがログイン処理の「Configure」でエラーとなり上手くいきません。
前提として以下を実行済みです。お知恵を貸していただければ幸いです。

＜実行済み＞
①gem install twitterの実行
②アプリをTwitterに登録
③access tokenを取得

＜エラー表示＞
console.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method`configure' for Twitter:Module (NoMethodError)

```
require 'twitter'
require './key'
require 'pp'

# ログイン
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = C_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = C_SEC
  config.oauth_token = A_TOKEN
  config.oauth_token_secret = A_SEC
end 

#自分宛てのDMの取得
pp Twitter.direct_messages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`undefined method`というのは「そんな名前のメソッドはありませんよ」というエラーです。
ようはTwitterモジュールの使い方が間違っています。

twitterって、このgemのことですよね？
http://sferik.github.io/twitter/

であるなら、exampleが載ってありますけど。

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```